# "R" write/export dataframe preserving the class information

Tags: r, dataframe

**Short Question**

> After formatting a dataframe in R with class information like "Date", "Factor", and etc. how to save the dataframe while preserving the class information. Consequently how to load the information back to a new R Project with preserving the above class information.

**Long Question**

I have created following dataframe with class information,

```
names <- c("Adrew", "Vikie", "Penny", "Samantha") 
date <- as.Date(c("1984-12-28", "1986-10-18", "1986-11-30", "1987-11-30"))
gender <- c("M", "M", "S", "S")

df <- data.frame(names, date, gender)

df$gender <- factor(df$gender,
                   levels = c("M", "S"), 
                   labels = c(1,2), 
                   order = FALSE)
```

[image: output1]

and the classes are factor, date, factor

**method 01**

then write the dataframe in csv format and read it

```
write.csv(df, "df.csv")
dfcsv <- read.csv("df.csv")
```

[image: output2]

and the daraframe classes are changed

**method 02**

then tried to write the file using table export method

```
write.table(df, "df.R")
dftable <- read.table("df.R")
```

[image: output3]

again the data frame classes had been changed

**Question**

> is there a proper method to write or save a data frame with preserving the **class** information like **date**, **factor**, etc information intact, and conversely how to load it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would be to save the data as an R data file using either `save()` or `saveRDS()`:

```
# option 1
save(df, file="data.Rdata")
load("data.Rdata")

# option 2
saveRDS(df, file="data2.Rds")
df <- readRDS("data2.Rds")
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Description

It is possible to write ASCII text representation of an **R** object with the use of `dput`, `dump`, `dget` and `source`. And with this it is possible to **preserve the class information**

### Method

#### saving the file

to save the file use the `dget` and/or `dump` function, *and to make sure that the file preserve the class information use the argument* `control = "all"`

the `dump` function take a list of dataframes as input which can be listed as `c("df", "df1", "df3")` and in the other hand `dput` will only output a single dataframe to a file.

**dput**

```
dput(df, file = "dput.R", control = "all")
```

**dump**

```
dump(c("df", "df2", "df3"), file = "dump.R", control = "all")
```

[image: initialDataFrame]

#### reading the file

to read the file use the `dget` function for `dput` files and `source` function for `dump` as mentioned,

**dput -> dget**

```
df3 <- dget(file =  "dput.R")
```

**dump -> source**

```
source("dump.R")
```

[image: outputDataFrame]